# Socket.IO removes all connections when browser is closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, dom-events

Server side code:

```
//When a user disconnects
  socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    console.log(rooms.length);
    var destroyThis = null;

    if(typeof socket.store.data.roomi == 'undefined'){
      for(var i in rooms){
        if(rooms[i].roomSocket.id == socket.id){
          destroyThis = rooms[i];
        }
      }
      if(destroyThis !== null){rooms.splice(destroyThis, 1);}
      console.log(rooms.length);
    }else{
      var roomId = socket.store.data.roomi;
      for(var i in rooms[roomId].mobileSockets){
        if(rooms[roomId].mobileSockets[i] == socket){
          destroyThis = i;
        }
      }
      if(destroyThis !== null){rooms[roomId].mobileSockets.splice(destroyThis, 1);}
      rooms[roomId].roomSocket.emit('remove user', socket.id);
    }
  });

    var express =require('express');
    var app = express()
        , http = require('http')
        , server = http.createServer(app)
        , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    server.listen(8080);

    app.configure(function(){
        app.use(express.methodOverride());
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(app.router);
    });

    app.configure('development', function(){
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));

    });

    app.configure('production', function(){
      var oneYear = 31557600000;
      app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
      app.use(express.errorHandler());

    });
```

Client side code:

```
socket.on('remove user', function(socketID){
      var destroyThis = null;
      for(var i in players){
        if(players[i].id == socketID){
          destroyThis = i;
        }
      }
      if(destroyThis !== null){ players.splice(destroyThis, 1);}

  });
```

When I attempt to close one browser tab without connection on a mobile platform, it closes all the active connections. What should I do in order to avoid this behavior?

EDIT: I have tried with both v0.99 and v1.0 of socket.IO. This is the debug info

info  - transport end (socket end)

debug - set close timeout for client HTAVoq8f22uRDvSrHxT2

debug - cleared close timeout for client HTAVoq8f22uRDvSrHxT2

debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client HTAVoq8f22uRDvSrHxT2

2

1

debug - discarding transport

debug - emitting heartbeat for client Fqli8YOR_cjF-3PeHxT0

debug - websocket writing 2::

debug - set heartbeat timeout for client Fqli8YOR_cjF-3PeHxT0

debug - got heartbeat packet

debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client Fqli8YOR_cjF-3PeHxT0

debug - set heartbeat interval for client Fqli8YOR_cjF-3PeHxT0